# select DISTINCT de 3 columnas

Tags: sql-server

intento generar una consulta aplicando el DISTINCT en 3 columnas pero no logro obtener el resultado esperado. Si no agrupo la columna "grupo" si obtengo el resultado esperado pero necesito obtener tambien cual es su grupo mas reciente

```
SELECT DISTINCT max ([Id])
  , [nombre]
  ,[apellido_paterno]
  ,[apellido_materno]
  ,[grupo] FROM [personas] group by [nombre], [apellido_paterno], [apellido_materno],[grupo]
```

Esta es la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que obtener el registro con el id mas alto de cada persona, por ejemplo de los registros marcados en amarillo y en verde se obtendria los registros 4 y 6. El registro en naranja no se tomaria en cuenta por que tiene otro apellido materno

Este es el resultado esperado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco mucho cualquier tipo de orientación

saludos

Comment: ¿Cómo defines cual es el grupo más reciente? Ahí no hay fechas.

Comment: Podria ser por el nombre del grupo no? y el ID podria particionarse y tomar el mas alto ejemplo juan daria con ROW_NUMBER 1 y 2 y siempre tomariamos el mas alto... es una idea

Comment: asi es, se tomaria del id mas alto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola aqui te anexo algo que podria ayudarte.

Tal como te puse en el comentario usariamos el row_number de igual manera anexo un comentario para que te puedas dar una idea de lo que realiza te dejo mas info del row_number para futuras dudas.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
ID INT,
Nombre VARCHAR(100),
Ap VARCHAR(100),
AM VARCHAR(100),
Grupo VARCHAR(100)
)


INSERT INTO @T VALUES(1,'JUAN','PEREZ','LOPEZ','GR1')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(2,'MARIA','MENDEZ','GONZALES','GR1')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(3,'Genaro','MARQUEZ','GONZALES','GR1')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(4,'JUAN','PEREZ','LOPEZ','GR2')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(5,'MONICA','SANCHEZ','GONZALES','GR2')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(6,'MARIA','MENDEZ','GONZALES','GR3')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(7,'MARCOS','MENDIENTA','GOMEZ','GR3')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(8,'JUAN','PEREZ','AGUILAR','GR3')


;WITH RESULT AS (
SELECT 
Nombre,Ap,AM,Grupo,ID,
--CREAMOS UN ROW PARA OBTENER ,1,2,3 ETC por cada coincidencia Ordenando por ID desc para que tome el mas reciente y ese siempre deje en la posicion 1
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NOMBRE,AP,AM ORDER BY ID DESC) AS RN
FROM @T
)
SELECT 
ID,Nombre,Ap,AM,Grupo
FROM RESULT WHERE RN=1
ORDER BY ID
```

Aqui el ejemplo funcional
https://dbfiddle.uk/KYTPz87Z